# select greatest date

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT distinct person, address, from_date, to_date 
  FROM db
 WHERE '2000-01-01' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
```

This is fine, however it brings back some people with multiple addresses on the 1st january 2000. I want to only select the addresses with the greatest to_date.

Ie if the query returns:

```
person-------------address--------from_date--------to_date
1------------------34-------------1999-06-12-------2000-04-04 
1------------------27-------------1999-06-12-------2000-12-12
```

I'd want to select only the second row.

Would doing the following suffice?

```
SELECT distinct person, address,from_date, MAX(to_date) 
  FROM db
WHERE '2000-01-01' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp types - always explicitly qualify your ranges.  It's also usually best to use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query could be something like (this can be further simplified though):

```
SELECT db.person, address, from_date,db.to_date
  FROM db, (SELECT person, max(to_date) to_date
            FROM db
           GROUP BY person) db_max
WHERE '2000-01-01' BETWEEN db.from_date AND db.to_date
  AND db.to_date = db_max.to_date
  AND db.person = db_max.person;
```

Comment: does this only bring back people who have multiple addresses? If they only have one address, I want to select those as default, and then for those that have multiple, select the one with the max(to_date)

Comment: No this will bring all the person . But for multiple addresses it will select the record with max to_date. Hence it will display single record for a person. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: excellent - just finished querying and this works as said. thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, always explicitly qualify your joins.  Don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause); it mostly works for inner joins, but causes weird issues with `LEFT JOIN`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT person, address,from_date, to_date
  FROM db db_outer
 WHERE '2000-01-01' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM db db_inner
                WHERE db_outer.person = db_inner.person
             GROUP BY db_inner.person
               HAVING MAX(db_inner.to_date) = db_outer.to_date)
```

Comment: thanks - this makes sense to me. hadn't thought of a sub-querey

Comment: just running this - does this only bring back people who have more than 1 addresses? it appears so? if you take out the "and exists" part of the querey I get a certain number, however if I include the exists clause I get half them number. I am not expecting the population to change.

Comment: No, it's not that way. If there's a single address for a person, it will show up. If there are multiple addresses for a single person, the most recent (`MAX(db_inner.to_date)`) address will show up. Try the query, you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

you need a subquery: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html is the best explanation, the sub query can have an order by as you have a "top"